# How do Bulk operations in Cloudant account for Bluemix pricing? (throughput - lookups, writes, queries)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Let's say I use a Bulk operation to create 3 new documents in Cloudant (Bluemix Standard plan).

Taking writes per second indicator into consideration:

Does this call account as "3 write operations" or "1 write operation"?

Thanks in before hand.

Comment: This is probably a question for support@cloudant.com or Bluemix support

Answer (score 0):

A bulk operation that creates 3 documents still counts as 1 write operation.