# Cloudant pricing question, using bulk API

Tags: cloudant

I'm seeing conflicting info on this. If I make 1 request to bulk insert 10 documents, how many write operations does that count for?

These two SO posts suggest 1, but I'm wondering if they are outdated.

[How do calculate IO operations in Cloudant account for Bluemix pricing? (throughput - lookups, reads, writes, queries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421425/how-do-calculate-io-operations-in-cloudant-account-for-bluemix-pricing-through)
[How do Bulk operations in Cloudant account for Bluemix pricing? (throughput - lookups, writes, queries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702951/how-do-bulk-operations-in-cloudant-account-for-bluemix-pricing-throughput-lo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you refer to is correct. A bulk write will (currently) be counted as a single write, and not be split apart into its constituent documents when it comes to billing.

However: note that Cloudant has always recommended that you don’t rely on this behaviour, as it might change somewhere down the line.

Stefan @ Cloudant